# modulus identity with roots of unity

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $\omega_n=e^{\frac{\pi i}{2n+1}}$. I've an experimental encounter with certain relation involving roots of unity.

> **Question.** Is this true? If yes, any proof? For $p\geq0$ an integer, we have the identity
>   $$\sum_{j=1}^n\left\vert\frac{1-\omega_n^{2j}}{1+\omega_n^{2j}}\right\vert^{2p}=
> \sum_{j=1}^n\left\vert \frac{1+\omega_n^{2j-1}}{1-\omega_n^{2j-1}}\right\vert^{2p}.$$

Comment: I noticed a down vote. What a shame! If you've valid reasons, you need to out come out and say so. Moderators would need to intervene in such matters. I've seen good questions (not mine) being subjected to this type of exercise from random users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that 
$$\frac{1-\omega_n^{2j}}{1+\omega_n^{2j}}\cdot\frac{1-\omega_n^{2n-2j+1}}{1+\omega_n^{2n-2j+1}}=\frac{(1+\omega_n^{2n+1})-(\omega_n^{2j}+\omega_n^{2n-2j+1})}{(1+\omega_n^{2n+1})+(\omega_n^{2j}+\omega_n^{2n-2j+1})} = -\frac{\omega_n^{2j}+\omega_n^{2n-2j+1}}{\omega_n^{2j}+\omega_n^{2n-2j+1}}=-1.$$
So 
$$\left\vert\frac{1-\omega_n^{2j}}{1+\omega_n^{2j}}\right\vert=\left\vert\frac{1+\omega_n^{2n-2j+1}}{1-\omega_n^{2n-2j+1}}\right\vert$$
and your identity follows by raising to the appropriate power and summing over $j\in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$.